# keeping certain values from list and dict

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary, text

I have a dict `d`

```
d = {'A1': ['Mike', 'Mouse'],
 'A2': ['Don', 'Duck'],
 'A3': ['Bart','Simp']}
```

and a list `l`

```
l = ['Sar', 'Mike', 'Duck', 'Hox12', 'Bart', '10r']
```

My goal is to create a new list `new_l` that does not have the items in `l` e.g. `Mike` that are also in `d` e.g. `'A1': ['Mike', 'Mouse']`.

I would like my `new_l` to be

```
new_l = ['Sar', 'Hox12', '10r]
```

I have tried

```
new_l = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if v not in l:
        new_l.append(v)
```

and

```
new_l = []
for names in l:
    if names not in v in d.items():
        new_l.append(names)
```

But they both do not give me my desired output.

How do I change my code to get my desired `new_l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use extend functionality to prepare a list using dict values.

```
new_l = []
d = {'A1': ['Mike', 'Mouse'],
 'A2': ['Don', 'Duck'],
 'A3': ['Bart','Simp']}
l = ['Sar', 'Mike', 'Duck', 'Hox12', 'Bart', '10r']
to_cmp_l = []
for k,v in d.items():
    to_cmp_l.extend(v)
for item in l:
    if item not in to_cmp_l:
        new_l.append(item)
print(new_l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = set()
for v in d.values():
    s |= set(v)
new_l = [e in l if e not in s]
```

convert each value to set and build a set of all values in the dictionary. Build the new list by checking for membership in the set.

You could use a list instead of a set, though a set has certain advantages, namely that elements are unique and the membership test is  a constant time operation.

`|=` is shorthand for adding elements to an existing set. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one-liner:

```
new_l = reduce(list.__add__, [list(set(items) - set(l)) for items in d.values()])
```